# Firebase functions to get a ajax post and console.log it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, firebase

Basically what I want to do is: post with ajax a startdate, enddate from a calendar when a button is pressed, send that to a nodejs backend written on a firebase function cloud ([some official docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)) and console.log that.

This is my ajax:

```
$("#get_excel_button").click(function() {
    var startdate = moment($("#filter_date_from").val(), "D MMMM, YYYY").unix();
    var enddate = moment($("#filter_date_to").val(), "D MMMM, YYYY").unix();
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://us-central1-ecc-local.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax',
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate},
    success: function (data) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#lblResponse').html(ret.msg);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        $('#lblResponse').html('Error connecting to the server.');
    },
});
});
```

And this is my node on the firebase functions side:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const express = require('express')


exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("test 1");
});
exports.getAjax = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.send("test 2");
        const app = express();
        var date = '';
        var startdate = '';
        var enddate = '';
        request.on('data', function(data) 
        {
            var date = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('Sending Formatted date:', date);
            response.status(200).send(date);
            response.status(200).end();
        });
        request.on('end', function() 
        {   
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "json");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.end(date);        
        });
    });  
});
```

The problems are:
My getAjax in the network at the response will output just `test 2` , but won't list my date var value, I try with console.log, won't work, also I get this Error coming from Ajax I think:

> Error: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1

And if I check my firebase console on the functions I have this log when I make the call:

> 10:31:38.859 AM getAjax Function execution took 210 ms, finished with
>   status code: 200 10:31:38.650 AM   getAjax  Billing account not
>   configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely
>   limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

My form data is looking like this:

```
startdate:1505941200
enddate:1506373200
```

I can't figure what is wrong here, how I can output in the response my date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're using the `cors` package properly in your Cloud Function code. Can you try to modify your Cloud Functions code to something like :

```
exports.getAjax = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        console.log("request.body :", JSON.stringify(request.body)); // Your data should be available here
        console.log("request.query :", JSON.stringify(request.query)); // Maybe check request.query too

        // Build JavaScript object out of request parameters
        var date = {
          startdate: request.body.startdate, 
          enddate: request.body.enddate
        }

        // Send JavaScript object as JSON (you're actually sending
        // a JavaScript object if you use JSON.parse())
        response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(date));
    }
})
```

I'm sorry I did not test this code, but this should give you some insight on how to clean up your server side code. Here is an example of how to user the `cors` package with Google Cloud Functions :
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js

Now, on the client side, I had the following code successfully running in my Chrome console (data is actually logged in the console), so I guess we're getting closer :-)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://us-central1-ecc-local.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax',
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {startdate: 1505941200, enddate: 1506373200},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Got data", data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log('status: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    },
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, now it's working, but I still get the: VM139:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1, but I can see in the console startdate and enddate, nice one, thank you, one small thing to add, at the last 2 ,,}'' you missed   }); to properly close the function.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the answer and added an Ajax code sample ran from a Chrome console, we're almost there !